# Comparing 2 columns in data-frame Value Error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame `df1` which looks like:

```
  ID  myColA  myColB myColC
0  A       1       5     13
1  B      -2       6     14
2  C       3      -7     15
3  D       4       8     16
```

I am trying to add a new column `myColD` that is filled on the result of the following:

```
myColD = ((myColA > 0 and myColB <0) or (myColA < 0 and myColB > 0)),0,myColA)
```

where row value in `myColA` is above 0 and value in `myColB` is below 0 or vice versa return 0, else return the `myColA` value.

So my desired output would be:

```
  ID  myColA  myColB myColC myColD
0  A       1       5     13      1
1  B      -2       6     14      0  
2  C       3      -7     15      0
3  D       4       8     16      4
```

Here is my code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'myColA': [1, -2, 3, 4],
    'myColB': [5, 6, -7, 8],
    'myColC': [9, 10, 11, 12]},
     index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df1['myColD'] = np.where(((df1.myColA > 0) & (df1.myColB < 0)) or ((df1.myColA < 0) & (df1.myColB > 0)), df1.myColA, 0)
```

I am however getting a Value Error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Just replace the `or` with the operator `|`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) for this. So use a `bitwise or`: `|` instead of `or`.

Also note that you could simplify this by checking where the product between both columns results in a negative value, and set the corresponding values to `0` with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df1['myColD'] = df1.myColA.mask(df1.myColA.mul(df1.myColB).lt(0), 0)
```

---

```
print(df1)

   ID  myColA  myColB  myColC  myColD
0  A       1       5       9       1
1  B      -2       6      10       0
2  C       3      -7      11       0
3  D       4       8      12       4
​
```

Answer (score 0):

point to the columns like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'myColA': [1, -2, 3, 4],
    'myColB': [5, 6, -7, 8],
    'myColC': [9, 10, 11, 12]},
     index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df1['myColD'] = np.where(((df1['myColA'] > 0) & (df1['myColB'] < 0)) | ((df1['myColA'] < 0) & (df1['myColB'] > 0)), df1['myColA'], 0)
print(df1)
```